# Enter iPad passcode screen is weird in portrait mode

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, passcode

I've this weird screen orientation showing up for enter iPad passcode on my login screen when I tap on saved password in landscape mode. The strange thing is that when I rotate screen to landscape mode and go to portrait mode it shows correctly first time but after that it again starts showing up weirdly.

It seems that it is trying to present passcode screen in landscape orientation on device's portrait mode.

This issue doesn't occur when device is in landscape mode.

Is it to do with something in my code? How to fix it or go about finding out the problem?

[image: iPad]

Comment: *"Is it to do with something in my code?"* -- ummmm, Yes, the problem is on line ## of your code. Might make it easier to get help if you actually show the code.

Comment: Could you post the relevant code?

Comment: Seriously? What code? This is launched on tap to save password. It has nothing to do with any code. I'm surprised that two of you asked to show code. I don't think he has added any code to show saved password, he must be talking about the default saved password icon tap which shows up automatically on the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is either a bug in iOS or something went wrong with your device. The solution is to update iOS to the latest version or restart the device.

Comment: I updated iOS and I no longer see this issue. Tx for pointing out.